# How to reset a queue in IBM MQ?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

How do i reset a queue? I want to clear all the messages in the queue, before i start to write a message into a queue. Is there any way i can reset without doing a get call?

```
MQQueueManager mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqQueueManager);
MQQueue queue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(getMessageQueue, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);
```

There is a .clearmessages in MQMessage object, but i can access that only when i call a get method, i am looking for a way to clear the existing messages in the queue, before i can put a new message into the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messages in a queue can be programatically cleared only with `Get` calls. There is no other way. Alternatively you use the administrative console to clear messages but that's not what you are looking for.

MQMessage.ClearMessage() discards any data in the **message buffer** and sets the data offset back to zero. It does not clear all the messages residing in a queue.

May I ask you why you want to clear the queue before putting new messages? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks, 2 applications will be used to put/get messages to/from same queue, i want to make sure the queue is empty before i put/get from my application(programmatically).

Answer (score 1):

For clearing messages from a queue you can use the 'Clear Queue' PCF command. As I know, it clears queue faster than GET call, but you can use it only on closed queues. You can read about it in IBM MQ Infocenter: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzac.doc/pc11350_.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of programs that you can use:

- ClearQ is a C program that issues MQSC Clear Q command but it will only work if no application has the queue open (restriction of the Clear Q command).  ClearQ program can be found here: http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_c.html
- EmptyQ is a Java program that uses MQGET to sequentially remove all messages from the queue.  EmptyQ can be found here: http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_java.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help!

```
 private Color[] FloodTest(Color[] color, TouchLocation touch, Texture2D tex)
    {

        Queue<Point> q = new Queue<Point>();
        q.Enqueue(pt);
        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            if (q.Count > 800000) break; 
        }

        q.Clear();
        q = null;
        return color;
    }
```

I removed not important code. Please look at q.Count.